# android pinch zoom in Unity 5 UI image panel

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine

Help, I'm trying to add zoom in/out pinch gesture on an image panel how can I do that?
I'm Using Unity 5, Currently I just display static image on UI image component and I want to add zoom in/out gesture there, how can I do that?

I did use mask and scroll bar to scroll text, can I do similar thing for zoom gesture?

PS: currently my image looks blur, is it because I resize it in unity? do I need image with bigger resolution? I've some concern on file size for deployment to google store.

Please help it's my first unity project....

Answer (score 0):

You can check this video: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/pinch-zoom
The main idea is that you should use `Input` class, not the scroll elements.

To avoid blurry image you should use texture with higher resolution. Disabling mipmaps in texture settings also can help.

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution:

```
void Update() {
    Zoom(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel"));
}
void Zoom(float increment) {
    currentScale += increment;
    if (currentScale >= maxScale) {
        currentScale = maxScale;
    } else if (currentScale <= minScale) {
        currentScale = minScale;
    }
    imageToZoom.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector2(currentScale, 
currentScale);
}
```